# Magento 2.2 Paypal payment method option not showing in checkout

Tags: php, magento, paypal, payment, magento2.2

After upgrade to magento from 2.1.7 to 2.2.1 the paypal method is not showing in payment method list in checkout.

main.CRITICAL: PayPal NVP gateway errors: Security header is not valid (#10002: Security error). Correlation ID: 77ca004062046. Version: 72.0. [] []

main.CRITICAL: PayPal gateway has rejected request. Security header is not valid (#10002: Security error). {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): PayPal gateway has rejected request. Security header is not valid (#10002: Security error). at /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111)"}

```
main.DEBUG: array (
  'url' => 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp',
  'getPalDetails' => 
  array (
    'METHOD' => 'getPalDetails',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'USER' => '****',
    'PWD' => '****',
    'SIGNATURE' => '****',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
  ),
  'response' => 
  array (
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2017-12-18T09:39:49Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => '77ca004062046',
    'ACK' => 'Failure',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '39206242',
    'L_ERRORCODE0' => '10002',
    'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Security error',
    'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => 'Security header is not valid',
    'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => 'Error',
  ),
) [] []
```

PayPal all-in-one solution I have enable in payment method.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you enable paypal solution and check paypal billing agreement solution on advance setting of paypal.